# How to arrange data lines

Tags: shell, sed

I need a help. I have a file like this:

```
-1.03 a b c
2.04 c b d
3.05 d b c
4.07 a n m
11.09 z y z
-12.52 o m n
13.04 u v t
14.05 a b j
21.06 j b c
22.01 n m h
23.05 i k m
-24.56 i o e
31.02 u a f
32.03 k l m
33.04 w d c
34.07 e i k
41.09 j o l
42.01 k p u
-43.06 o v m
44.55 h j l
```

I have no idea to arrange such data lines by bash shell by grouping line numbers: (1,5,9,13,17), (2,6,10,14,18), (3,7,11,15,19), (4,8,12,16,20) Could you please help me?

bash shell

I need to arrange lines and export results to another file like this:

```
-1.03 a b c
11.09 z y z
21.06 j b c
31.02 u a f
41.09 j o l

2.04 c b d
-12.52 o m n
22.01 n m h
32.03 k l m
42.01 k p u

3.05 d b c
13.04 u v t
23.05 i k m
33.04 w d c
-43.06 o v m

4.07 a n m
14.05 a b j
-24.56 i o e
34.07 e i k
44.55 h j l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no idea to arrange such data lines by bash shell by grouping
>   line numbers: `(1,5,9,13,17)`, `(2,6,10,14,18)`, `(3,7,11,15,19)`,
>   `(4,8,12,16,20)` Could you please help me?

If you do really want to **regroup those lines in this way**, then you can just use the following command:

```
for i in `seq 4`; do sed -n "$i~4p" file.txt; echo; done
-1.03 a b c
11.09 z y z
21.06 j b c
31.02 u a f
41.09 j o l

2.04 c b d
-12.52 o m n
22.01 n m h
32.03 k l m
42.01 k p u

3.05 d b c
13.04 u v t
23.05 i k m
33.04 w d c
-43.06 o v m

4.07 a n m
14.05 a b j
-24.56 i o e
34.07 e i k
44.55 h j l
```

loop on `i` from `1` to `4`; run the `sed` command to print from line `$i + i+4, i+8,...` then `echo` will add an empty line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following :

```
rev filename.txt | sort | rev | sed 's/^\(.\)$/\n\1/g'
```

Explanation :

- Sort from right to left
- insert a new line before each single digit number.

Comment: You can simplify your command into: `rev filename.txt | sort | rev | sed 's/^\(.\)$/\n\1/g'`

Comment: Actually you should change your command into: `$ rev filename.txt | sort | rev | sed 's/^\([^1]\)$/\n\1/g'` because it generates one empty line at the beginning of the file, anyway +1!

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear question. I aim to rearrange lines, not to sort data. I tried to edit my question. Could you please help me? I really appreciate your help! Best regards!

Comment: @BinhThien I think you should ask another question and revert to the original for this one. Since this wonderful solution already includes your previous needs exactly.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: your question is completely different than what you originally asked... anyway I have answered to it.